# My if statement takes me to the same query each time when its supposed to be varied dependent on my option

Tags: php

I think there is something wrong with my if statement since when i choose an the teacher option on the previous page, it makes me go through the student option.

My if statement takes me to the same query each time when its supposed to be varied dependent on my option

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'databaseclass.php';
$br = "<br>";
$db = new databaseclass($pdo);

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$salt = 'itnvv7b96t8ug679ytfj89';
$hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array(
    'salt' => $salt 
));

$option = $_POST["option"];
//if statement Correction
if($option == "student"){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$hashedpassword."'";
    $db -> query ($sql);
    $rows = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
    $count = count($rows);

        foreach ($rows as $results){
          $studentID = $results->studentID;
          $firstName = $results->firstName;
          $surname = $results->surname;
          $email = $results->email;
        }

        if ($count == 1){
            session_start();

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['studentID'] = $results->studentID;
            $_SESSION['firstName'] = $results->firstName;
            $_SESSION['surname'] = $results->surname;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $results->email;

            header('Location:studenthomepage.php');
        }

        else {
            session_start();  
            session_destroy();
            header('Location:login.html');
        }

}

else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE `email`='".$email."' AND `password`='".$hashedpassword."'";
    $db -> query ($sql);
    $rows = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
    $count = count($rows);

    foreach ($rows as $results){
      $teacherID = $results->teacherID;
      $firstName = $results->firstName;
      $surname = $results->surname;
      $email = $results->email;

    }

        if ($count == 1){
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['teacherID'] = $results->teacherID;
        $_SESSION['firstName'] = $results->firstName;
        $_SESSION['surname'] = $results->surname;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $results->email;

        header('Location:teacherhomepage.php');

      }

        else {
        session_start();  
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:login.html');
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should be
 `if($option == "student")` Instead of `if($option = "student")`

Try This. It may work.

Comment: @DMat did it work?

Comment: accept the solution if it worked..thank you